# Pagination with Twig

Tags: php, pagination, templating, twig

I've been trying Twig, and it works well for my small site.

This was the tutorial used:

http://devzone.zend.com/article/13633

However, I've had a look online and cannot find anything to do pagination.

This is my code:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }        
      tr.heading {      
        font-weight: bolder;
      }        
      td {
        border: 0.5px solid black;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
      }    
    </style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Automobiles</h2>
    <table>
      <tr class="heading">
        <td>Vehicle</td>
        <td>Model</td>
        <td>Price</td>
      </tr> 
      {% for d in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ d.manufacturer|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.model|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.price|raw }}</td>
      </tr> 
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the PHP coding for it:

```
<?php
// include and register Twig auto-loader
include 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// attempt a connection
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=world;host=localhost', 'root', 'mypass');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage();
}

// set error mode
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// attempt some queries
try {
  // execute SELECT query
  // store each row as an object
  $sql = "SELECT manufacturer, model, price FROM automobiles";
  $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
  while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  // close connection, clean up
  unset($dbh); 

  // define template directory location
  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');

  // initialize Twig environment
  $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

  // load template
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('automobiles.tpl');

  // set template variables
  // render template
  echo $template->render(array (
    'data' => $data
  ));

} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

What would I need to do to get the results paginated within Twig?
Otherwise my site works perfectly well!

thanks, JC

Answer (score 5):

Since Twig is just a template engine, there is nothing included (at least in the core) to add pagination. You have to split the content by yourself and paginate it (for example using JavaScript). Keep in mind that with your current implementation the **complete** content is inserted into the template and you would only hide/show some parts of it.

The preferred way however, would be to include the paging also in your model (the part where you do your query) to load only these records, which are currently shown to the user. This is obviously out of the scope of a template engine.

Answer (score 5):

There are already examples in the internet. You may refer to

https://gist.github.com/SimonSimCity/4594748

Comment: @XFS: Please keep in mind, that these are just examples for displaying the page-browser. The logic for page limit and offset is something you still have to take care of. You'd still need to adjust your model, controller and so on as apfelbox writes.